# Can we extend checked/unchecked exceptions in java

Tags: java, exception, inheritance

Can we extend checked/unchecked exceptions in java. If yes can we have any samples. Please provide samples if any available.

Comment: *"If yes can we have any samples."*  1) Please add a question mark to questions.  2) SO is not a code factory or your personal help-desk.  Why not explain what you think and why you think it?  (Try showing some effort.) 3) Is this [tag:homework]?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes

```
//checked exception extended    
class MyCheckedException extends Exception{
}

//unchecked exception extended
class MyUncheckedException extends RuntimeException{
}
```

Unchecked exceptions are those exceptions which extend RuntimeException (or any subclasses thereof), while checked ones extend any Exception class (Exception, IOException that is NOT a subclass of RuntimeException.